# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'saldoConta'

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Estou iniciando os estudos em POO com python e fiz um teste de uma classe `ContaBancaria` bem simples, cujos métodos seriam apenas saque e depósito. Porém quando vou interagir com o usuário, não consigo atribuir as variáveis aos meus atributos.
Segue o código abaixo.

Criando a classe:

```
class ContaBancaria:
  def __init__(self, saldoConta: float, valorDesejado: float):
    self.saldoConta = saldoConta
    self.valorDesejado = valorDesejado

  def saque(self):
    self.saldoConta += self.valorDesejado

  def deposito(self):
    self.saldoConta -= self.valorDesejado

  def mostraSaldo(self):
    return self.saldoConta
```

Interagindo com o usuário:

```
print("BEM-VINDO AO SISTEMA DE CONTA BANCÁRIA")
print("\n")
print("=" * 20)

valorAtual = float(input("SALDO ATUAL: R$ "))
ContaBancaria(saldoConta=valorAtual, valorDesejado=0)


print("DIGITE\n1. SAQUE\n2. DEPOSITO")
tipo_de_operacao = int(input())
valor_desejado = print('Valor desejado: ')

if tipo_de_operacao == 1:  
  ContaBancaria.saque(valor_desejado)

elif tipo_de_operacao == 2:
  ContaBancaria.deposito(valor_desejado)

else:
  pass

print("OBRIGADO POR UTILIZAR O NOSSO SISTEMA. =) ")
```

O erro apresentado:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'saldoConta'`

Comment: Quando você instancia a classe `ContaBancaria` você não armazena a instância em nenhuma variável, depois chama os métodos como se fossem métodos estáticos. Atribua a instância a uma variável e a utilize para chamar os métodos.

Comment: E `valor_desejado = print('Valor desejado: ')` não faz sentido, pois `valor_desejado` sempre será `None`, que é o retorno da função `print`. Se a ideia é ler o valor, use `input`.

Comment: Ah, isso aí foi sem querer kkk. Já consertei. Obrigada!

Comment: Eu fiz isso e deu certo. Eu tenho mais duas perguntas: eu fiz com que cada atributo fosse igual a zero, porém não precisava disso, correto? E também tentei printar o saldo atual para o usuário, porém não consegui. Coloquei print em cada método na classe, nos `if` também e não deu. Alguma sugestão?

Já agradeço muito pela ajuda!

Comment: Oi @BeatrizGomes pode atualizar o código? Assim vou entender melhor o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Oi, William. Vou mandar o código atualizado, já consegui rodá-lo.

Comment: Primeiro: Você ainda possui dúvidas? Segundo, não use a área de respostas assim, edite a sua pergunta ao invés disso. @BeatrizGomes

Comment: Não, sem dúvidas. Já foi resolvido.